# kaminari undefined method `total_pages'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kaminari

While using kaminari, I got an error.

Gemfile:

```
# gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.6'
# gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'

gem 'kaminari'
```

lists_controller.rb

```
  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @lists = List.tagged_with(params[:tag]).order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page:params[:page], per_page: 3 )
    else
      @lists = List.all.order(created_at: :desc)
    end
  end
```

I also user `.page params[:page].per(2)` follow `.order(created_at: :desc)`
but not work

views/lists/index.html.erb

```
<%= paginate @lists %>
```

the error is here

```
undefined method `total_pages' for #<List::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fa2303e3fa8>
Extracted source (around line #26):             
    </div>
  </div>
<%= paginate @lists %>
  <div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
```

I was following a railscasts video about kaminari, but they did not have any error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to paginate both queries. I recommend something like:

```
def index
  if params[:tag]
    @lists = List.tagged_with(params[:tag])
  else
    @lists = List.all
  end
  @lists = @lists.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page:params[:page], per_page: 3 )
end
```

Otherwise `@lists` will not be a pagination object when `params[:tag]` is nil.

Comment: Thanks a million! It work ,very very thanks.  add @list . user .page(params[:page]).per(5)

  ```  @lists = @lists.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per(5) ```
the page OK.

Comment: @user5590209 If I've solved your problem please accept my answer by hitting the check mark next to it.

Comment: thanks remind, I am new come here. now is it ok ? choose your answer is best and chick nike logo.

Answer (score 1):

Try to paginate with:

```
 List.tagged_with(params[:tag]).order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per(3)
```

Comment: Works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, it was because the commontator gem was bringing in methods from will_paginate and overriding the base ActiveRecord class.

The error was in the call stack for the page_entries_info method which seems to be a common method name between both libraries.

To fix, you can explicitly reference the method with this:

So the view code:

```
      <%= Kaminari::Helpers::HelperMethods.page_entries_info @events %>
      <%= link_to "Next", path_to_next_page(@events) %>
      <%= link_to "Prev", path_to_prev_page(@events) %>
```

and in an initializer (initializers/kaminari_config.rb)

```
module Kaminari
  module Helpers
    module HelperMethods
      extend ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper
      module_function :page_entries_info
    end
  end
end
```

This is a very hacky fix, but hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
order(:nome).page page
```

Worked for me