# Multiple IF statements in Rails 5 Controller

Tags: controller, ruby-on-rails-5, kaminari

I am trying to use two if statements within my index.  The first allows the user to view by tags, and the second defines the Kaminari pagination gem, `gem 'kaminari'`.

The problem is, I can't get both to work. With the code as is below, the pagination works, but filtering by tag does not. If I comment out the pagination, the the tags work.

I'm fairly sure I don't have the correct logic around the two if statements, but I can't work out how to right this.

```
class CoffeeshopsController < ApplicationController


  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @coffeeshops = Coffeeshop.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @coffeeshops = Coffeeshop.all.order("created_at DESC").page params[:page]
    end

    if params[:term]
      @coffeeshops = Coffeeshop.search_by_full_name(params[:term])
    else
      @coffeeshops = Coffeeshop.all.order("created_at DESC").page params[:page]
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting @coffeshops in the second `if` block. Having said that, you should put the pagination after all filtering.

```
  def index
    @coffeeshops = Coffeeshop.all
    if params[:tag]
      @coffeeshops = @coffeeshops.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    end
    if params[:term]
      @coffeeshops = @coffeeshops.search_by_full_name(params[:term])
    end
    # paginate
  end
```

Comment: ok, makes sense.  I now however get `undefined method `total_pages'` on calling `<%= paginate @coffeeshop %>` in my view, but that might be more specific to Kaminari.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with the below.  Thanks to another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070991/kaminari-undefined-method-total-pages?rq=1) question.

```
def index
  if params[:tag]
    @coffeeshops = Coffeeshop.tagged_with(params[:tag])
  else
    @coffeeshops = Coffeeshop.all
  end
  @coffeeshops = @coffeeshops.order("created_at DESC").page params[:page]
end
```

Important point I've also taken out the search term statement for now.